# How do the effects of a caloric surplus vary depending on macros?

Tags: body-fat, muscle-mass, bulking

I would like to better understand how a caloric surplus affects the body composition, mainly fat storage, based on the main macro that generates it.

From what I know,a caloric surplus is needed in order to gain weight,
while a caloric deficit will result in a weight loss.

In addition to this, there is also to consider the concepts of Glycemic Index and Glycemic Load.

Considering a [TDEE](https://tdeecalculator.net/result.php?s=metric&g=male&age=25&kg=77&cm=167&act=1.375&f=1) of about 2300 calories, and the goal of buliking up with a +500 calories surplus, what will be the difference in terms of body fat percentage and muscle mass, by approaching a moderate, low or high Carbs as displayed below?

[image: Bulking Macros]

Going to an extreme point, if by hypothesis one could follow a caloric surplus diet, composed just of 0 Glycemic Index and high quality proteins foods (e.g chicken breast, eggs, ...),
would it still be possible for him to gain body fat?
Or will it build just muscles?

What if instead one would follow a diet of just high Glycemic Index foods, like bread, pasta, biscuits, chocolate and so on?
Would it gain just body fat, or will it be able to build some muscles too?

Comment: It would be awesome to know the answer to this, but I don't think humans understand biology enough to be this specific yet. Certainly, no one here does. Human variability also makes it impossible to answer.